# Android compose nested lazy column scroll

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column, nested-scroll

I have the following UI in compose

Parent Lazy Column 1 {

// item 1

// item 2

// item 3 LazyColumn 2

}

Lazy Column 1 and LazyColumn 2 have device height.

use cases:

1. if the parent lazy column 1 scrolled till the end and item 3 LazyCoulmn 2 is fully visible, then only nested scroll should be enabled.
2. if item 3 is partial visible, then only parent scroll should be scrollable. Nested scroll should be disabled.
3. Also in nested lazy column 2 while scrolling its content, only once it reaches the top item parent should be scrolled.

In short summary, the scrolling should be synchronized together. Child should scroll only when parents other items has no scrolling left (item 1 and item2).  For child while scrolling up and it has no more scroll to handle, then parent should scroll.

I want to have 2 separate snapping behaviour for the 2 lazycolumn. So stuck here at the moment.

Tried few approach with disabling scroll, however did not find any proper key to be used in side effects.

Normal usage with 2 different lazyList state, I can still able to scroll nested lazy column even when its not fully visible.

Anyone has suggestions on what I can try? Any other approaches?